# How to use a certificate in an ALB target group HTTPS health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an HTTPS endpoint and I want my application loadbalancer (ALB)  to NOT terminate TLS and pass it through to the instances. How do I configure health checks on the target group to reach the instance? I don't see any option to set the TLS cert.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it can't be done via the ALB ,

use an NLB with TCP traffic configuration or classic ( being discontinued, so use it at your own risk)